# Including a directive in Angular - Missing template?

Tags: angularjs

I am currently implementing a slider in my Angular app. I am using this one: https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider

I have implemented the js file (version 2.8.0), the css file, registered the module within my app (rzModule), and am trying, to just display a slider: `<rzslider rz-slider-model="ctrl.priceSlider"></rzslider>`.

The slider does not show. Instead i am getting `"rzSliderTpl.html" not found`.
I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. The html file is not there, but it shouldt be. The template is added to the template cache at the end of the file (see https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/2.8.0/rzslider.js).

So, what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something in your code (perhaps any other included modules?) interfering with the templatecache, a very basic example using Angular 1.5.0 and version 2.8.0 of that slider works perfectly:

```js
angular.module('App', [
    'rzModule'
]);

angular.module('App').controller('Controller', [
    function () {
        this.value = 10;
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/2.8.0/rzslider.css" />
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/2.8.0/rzslider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
        <rzslider rz-slider-model="ctrl.value"></rzslider>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According Git repository, the rzslider directive - [line 1690](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/blob/master/src/rzslider.js) - it require a template html.

The src folder has the template: [rzSliderTpl.html](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/blob/master/src/rzSliderTpl.html). Once you download the template or create your own it should work fine.

Comment: Hmm, it says nowhere in there own description. And why is the template added to the template cache then. What could be the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the CDN, copy the rzSliderTpl.html from the src folder into the folder of your choice.

Then, modify line 1690 of the rzslider.js to point at your copy of rzSliderTpl.html

```
templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
  //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
  return attrs.rzSliderTplUrl || /path/to/folder/rzSliderTpl.html';
},
```